# Qt move text following a circular path

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am making a simple analog clock using Qt5, and I had this idea of printing the current time, for example the current seconds above the seconds hand. So the text holding the seconds value would move following the clock.

What I have until now is something like this

```
painter.save();

painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
pen.setBrush(Qt::white);
painter.rotate(360 * (time.second() / 60.0));
painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(0,30), 9, 9);

painter.restore();

painter.save();

QRect rec(0, 30, 10, 10);
painter.setPen(Qt::black);
QFont font = painter.font() ;
font.setPointSize(ampmTextSize());
painter.setFont(font);
QFontMetrics fm(font);
int pixelsWide = fm.width(time.toString("ss a").left(2));
int pixelsHigh = fm.height();
rec.setWidth(pixelsWide);
rec.setHeight(pixelsHigh);
painter.rotate(360 * (time.second() / 60.0));
painter.drawText(rec, Qt::AlignCenter, time.toString("ss"));

painter.restore();
```

Which of curse is not correct as it causes the text to rotate as can be seen from this image

[image]
[image]

Has anyone any idea on how to achieve this effect correctly in Qt?

EDIT
Something I forgot to mention is that I would hope for a solution involving Qt's functions and not using parametric equations of a circle or some similar solution, as this is just an exercise so I can train myself in using Qt.

If we simply wanted to get the coordinates that I would want to follow in order to trace the tip of the clocks' seconds hand then something like the equations here are enough

```
int posx = cos(((360 * (time.second() / 60.0)) * M_PI / 180) - ((90) * M_PI / 180)) * 30.0 + 0;

int posy = sin(((360 * (time.second() / 60.0)) * M_PI / 180) - ((90) * M_PI / 180)) * 30.0 + 0;
```

Yet I am more interested in learning an efficient way of doing this using the painter that Qt provides.

Comment: is it `QWidget` or `QGraphicsView` (`painter.save();` suggest graphics view).

Comment: Yes you are right, I am exploring QGraphicsView capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a quick example using `QGraphicsView`:

```
#include "analogclock.h"

#include <QTimer>
#include <QVector>
#include <QVector>
#include <QTime>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

#include <cmath>

AnalogClock::AnalogClock(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timeout()));
    timer->start(1000);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Analog Clock"));
    resize(200, 200);

    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    setScene(scene);
    scene->setSceneRect(QRect(-70,-70,140,140));

    static const QVector<QPointF> hourHand(QVector<QPointF>()
        << QPointF(7, 8)
        << QPointF(-7, 8)
        << QPointF(0, -40) );
    static const QVector<QPointF> minuteHand( QVector<QPointF>()
        << QPoint(7, 8)
        << QPoint(-7, 8)
        << QPoint(0, -70) );

    QColor hourColor(127, 0, 127);
    QColor minuteColor(0, 127, 127, 191);

    m_hour = scene->addPolygon(QPolygonF(hourHand), QPen(), QBrush(hourColor));
    m_minute = scene->addPolygon(QPolygonF(minuteHand), QPen(), QBrush(minuteColor));
    m_text = scene->addText("");

    timeout();
}

AnalogClock::~AnalogClock() { }
// This is a protected slot:
void AnalogClock::timeout()
{
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();

    m_hour->setRotation(30.0 * ((time.hour() + time.minute() / 60.0)));
    qreal mAngle(6.0 * ((time.minute() + time.second() / 60.0)));
    m_minute->setRotation(mAngle);
    m_text->setPos(70.0 * std::sin(mAngle * M_PI / 180.0), -70.0 * std::cos(mAngle * M_PI / 180.0));
    m_text->setPlainText(QString("%1").arg(time.minute()));
}
```

For `main.cpp` and header file you can use the Qt AnalogClock example and add the remaining members to it as private variables.

Answer (score 0):

You making your life complicated? Why you do this in single object?
You can easily do this using couple `QGgraphicsViewItem`s and no paint implementation is needed! You will avoid many problems with painting and performance.

Also if you will need add some mouse functionality it will be much easier to do.

Comment: That is exactly the reason why I posted the question here. I don't have the experience to do what you are suggesting, so if you have the time to write an example would be great.